# form submitted data is not saved into phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am using the below php code in my localhost on apache server, it shows no error and everything seems going fine when I submitted data in html form but the data is not saved in phpmyadmin table. Anyone can help?

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'xxxx';
$database = 'newtable';
$con = mysqli_connect("$servername","$username","$password","$database");
if (! $con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO newtable (firstname, lastname) VALUES  ('$_POST[firstname]', '$_POST[lastname]')";
if (! $sql)
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Record Added Successfully!";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and html code is:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
        Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br><br>
        Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br><br>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please Respond to the answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to execute your query and please use prepared statement like below

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO newtable (firstname, lastname) VALUES  (?, ?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $lastname);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Correct in more secure form!!

Answer (score 0):

You just write your query forget to execute it

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO newtable (firstname, lastname) VALUES  ('".$_POST['firstname']."', '".$_POST['lastname']."')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);// execute it

if (! $result)
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));// need to pass connection as parameter
}
```

read

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Better to use bind statement to prevent form sql injection

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO newtable (firstname, lastname) VALUES  (?, ?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $lastname);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: faster typer than I am today, well played!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't execute your insert query statement anywhere, so the data was not added.

Replace below line:

```
if (! $sql)
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}
```

with

```
if ($mysqli->query($con, $sql) !== TRUE)
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for you answers, It worked

all I needed to add $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

is it a execution of the program?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root'; 
$password = ''; 
$database = 'newtable'; $con = mysqli_connect("$servername","$username","$password","$database");
if (! $con){ die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error()); } 
$sql = "INSERT INTO yourTableName (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('".$_POST['firstname']."', '".$_POST['lastname']."')"; 
if (! $sql) { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error()); } echo "Record Added Successfully!"; mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

If you are using local host then the db password is blank by default and you need to give your table name in the insert query.